# Glassfish Server Administrator Credentials

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I am just trying to start my Glassfish 4.1 Server in Netbeans but it always gives me this window:[image]

I am 100% sure that the password and the username are correct and now I have no idea what to do.

Looking forward to answers,
Fabian